# Right way to hide sensitive content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If there are different types of users and there is some content that i want only a part of them to see which is the correct way to do this? Till now i used display:none to hide content but if the user inspects the page he could see it.

Example: There is a page (houses.php) with various houses and bellow every house there is the phone number of the owner which is hidden using display:none (through js) if the logged in user is not the administrator. How can i achieve the same result server-side?

Edit: Is the correct way to store users authority during log in to `$_SESSION['authority']` for example and then when the user visits houses.php  make an ajax call to the php file which will check if `$_SESSION['authority']` is enough to show users phone number. If it is enough it will store to `$_SESSION['phone_number']` the phone number if it's not it won't. Then in html decide to show or not show it by doing the following:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['authority'] == 1) {
?>

    <div name="phone_number"> Phone number : <?php echo $_SESSION["phone_number"]; ?> </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Or something like this?

```
<div name="phone_number">
    <?php
        if($_SESSION['authority'] == 1) 
        {
           echo "Phone number: ";
           echo $_SESSION["phone_number"];
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Is this a secure way to do it?

Comment: Hide it on the server. Any client side solution will still have the same issue you have now, ie. still visible when the page is inspected/source is viewed

Comment: Even if you overwrite the content with "null", that means the content has been on the screen before, which means that any user can find it if they know what they're doing.

Comment: Anything output will always be available in the source if a user views the source code for the page.  As Rory says, the best way is to use your server side language to validate the user and output the correct information depending on their role

Comment: do it server-side

Comment: And, don't use client side code to determine if it should be loaded. E.G. JavaScript that uses an AJAX call to pull in stuff for certain users, that's a no-no, as it can easily be hacked. Take all such decisions on the server.

Comment: Hey, who closed this question? It is an important one, that should be prominently present, on the home page here and in the HNQ list! And downvoting doesn't do anything good either!

Comment: Mr Lister that was actually what i thought to do ...i'm obviously kinda new to security issues.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want some client's to access some data, the only way is to not send it to them.

You must take into consideration that not all HTTP clients are even web browsers - some programs might replicate the behavior of the browser to get into your users data. If you rely on html/css/js to hide the sensitive information then it's only effective against humans looking at web browser and completely ineffective towards anything else.

So, all sensitive information has to be behind authorization & HTTPS. Nothing you can do in the browser is really secure.